# IF function issues

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to run multiple IF scenarios using this formula:

```
=IF(B6=$B$100,(IF(H6>75,$D$100,IF(H6>65,$D$101,IF(H6>55,$D$102,IF(H6>0,$D$103,
IF(B6=$B$105,(IF(H6>75,$D$105,IF(H6>65,$D$106,IF(H6>55,$D$107,IF(H6>0,$D$108,
IF(B6=$B$110,(IF(H6>75,$D$110,IF(H6>65,$D$111,IF(H6>55,$D$112,IF(H6>0,$D$113,
IF(B6=$B$115,(IF(H6>75,$D$115,IF(H6>65,$D$116,IF(H6>55,$D$117,IF(H6>0,$D$118,
     IF(B6=$B$120,(IF(H6>75,$D$120,IF(H6>65,$D$121,IF(H6>55,$D$122,IF(H6>0,$D$123,"Error"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

The issue is it will not look past the first line and will return "FALSE" if the answer doesn't equal cell B100, can anyone help me out?

Comment: It is possibly too complex - are you allowed to use VBA or does it have to be purely in formulae.

Comment: It has to be formulae I'm afraid to say

Comment: I see  =If(B6=$B$100,(...))  but that has no false condition that i can find. Anything that matches B100 will continue down the line but if it doesn't match it will return FALSE because you didn't supply a false output (If(condition, true, false)). Am I missing something?? Seems to be what you say you want.

Comment: Looks like you have too many IF( statements nested together
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/nested.htm

You will need to use VBA to sort through it all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the parentheses for the IFs testing H6 before you move on to the next test of B6.  I think you mean this:

```
=IF(B6=$B$100,IF(H6>75,$D$100,IF(H6>65,$D$101,IF(H6>55,$D$102,IF(H6>0,$D$103,"Error")))),
IF(B6=$B$105,IF(H6>75,$D$105,IF(H6>65,$D$106,IF(H6>55,$D$107,IF(H6>0,$D$108,"Error")))),
IF(B6=$B$110,IF(H6>75,$D$110,IF(H6>65,$D$111,IF(H6>55,$D$112,IF(H6>0,$D$113,"Error")))),
IF(B6=$B$115,IF(H6>75,$D$115,IF(H6>65,$D$116,IF(H6>55,$D$117,IF(H6>0,$D$118,"Error")))),
IF(B6=$B$120,IF(H6>75,$D$120,IF(H6>65,$D$121,IF(H6>55,$D$122,IF(H6>0,$D$123,"Error")))),
"Error"
)))))
```